# Jquery Flot library, how to make it work

Tags: jquery, flot

I am new to Flot and jquery library. I need to use flot to finish my project. And I am learning tutorial from http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/making-first-jquery-flot-line-chart.html
But when I download flot on the desktop and put the code below into flot directory. But nothing happened, only show the context of  Am I doing something wrong!!!! and     Read more at http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-line-chart.html#u48w025iOQr0VKZ4.99

I do not know where it is problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="query-1.10.2.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script> 
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.time.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jshashtable-2.1.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.numberformatter-1.2.3.min.js"></script>



    <script>
        //******* 2012 Gold Price Chart
        var data1 = [
            [gd(2012, 0, 1), 1652.21], [gd(2012, 1, 1), 1742.14], [gd(2012, 2, 1), 1673.77], [gd(2012, 3, 1), 1649.69],
            [gd(2012, 4, 1), 1591.19], [gd(2012, 5, 1), 1598.76], [gd(2012, 6, 1), 1589.90], [gd(2012, 7, 1), 1630.31],
            [gd(2012, 8, 1), 1744.81], [gd(2012, 9, 1), 1746.58], [gd(2012, 10, 1), 1721.64], [gd(2012, 11, 2), 1684.76]
        ];

        var data2 = [
            [gd(2012, 0, 1), 0.63], [gd(2012, 1, 1), 5.44], [gd(2012, 2, 1), -3.92], [gd(2012, 3, 1), -1.44],
            [gd(2012, 4, 1), -3.55], [gd(2012, 5, 1), 0.48], [gd(2012, 6, 1), -0.55], [gd(2012, 7, 1), 2.54],
            [gd(2012, 8, 1), 7.02], [gd(2012, 9, 1), 0.10], [gd(2012, 10, 1), -1.43], [gd(2012, 11, 2), -2.14]
        ];
        var dataset = [
            { label: "Gold Price", data: data1, points: { symbol: "triangle"} },
            { label: "Change", data: data2, yaxis: 2 }
        ];

        var options = {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true
                },
                points: {
                    radius: 3,
                    fill: true,
                    show: true
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                tickSize: [1, "month"],
                tickLength: 0,
                axisLabel: "2012",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 10
            },
            yaxes: [{
                axisLabel: "Gold Price(USD)",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 3,
                tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                    return $.formatNumber(v, { format: "#,###", locale: "us" });
                }
            }, {
                position: "right",
                axisLabel: "Change(%)",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 3
            }
          ],
            legend: {
                noColumns: 0,
                labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
                position: "nw"
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor: "#633200",
                backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }
            },
            colors: ["#FF0000", "#0022FF"]
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.plot($("#flot-placeholder1"), dataset, options);
            $("#flot-placeholder1").UseTooltip();
        });




        function gd(year, month, day) {
            return new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
        }

        var previousPoint = null, previousLabel = null;
        var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

        $.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
            $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                if (item) {
                    if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
                        previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
                        previousLabel = item.series.label;
                        $("#tooltip").remove();

                        var x = item.datapoint[0];
                        var y = item.datapoint[1];

                        var color = item.series.color;
                        var month = new Date(x).getMonth();

                        //console.log(item);

                        if (item.seriesIndex == 0) {
                            showTooltip(item.pageX,
                            item.pageY,
                            color,
                            "<strong>" + item.series.label + "</strong><br>" + monthNames[month] + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>(USD)");
                        } else {
                            showTooltip(item.pageX,
                            item.pageY,
                            color,
                            "<strong>" + item.series.label + "</strong><br>" + monthNames[month] + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>(%)");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    previousPoint = null;
                }
            });
        };

        function showTooltip(x, y, color, contents) {
            $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y - 40,
                left: x - 120,
                border: '2px solid ' + color,
                padding: '3px',
                'font-size': '9px',
                'border-radius': '5px',
                'background-color': '#fff',
                'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                opacity: 0.9
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:450px;height:300px;text-align:center;margin:10px">       
        <div id="flot-placeholder1" style="width:300%;height:300%;"></div>       
    </div>
    <p>Am I doing something wrong!!!!</p>
</body>
</html>

Read more at http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-line-chart.html#u48w025iOQr0VKZ4.99
```

Comment: I would recommend starting small and build up to the result you want. Try to duplicate this simple graph first - http://jsfiddle.net/KMTjZ/3/

Comment: @Blake yes, it is working... but why the code above did not display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before checking the code for errors seriously related to jquery flot, I suggest you to be sure that the "basic" things are correct.
For example, I can see that you are importing "query-1.10.2.min.js" (`<script src="query-1.10.2.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>`), in my mind this can probably be a typo (jquery-1.10.2.min.js?).

Please use even the developer console to check that all the imported files (javascripts and eventually CSSs) are currently pointing to an existent resource.

Comment: I deleted the query-1.10.2.min.js... and all files are pointing to the correct rescource.. but still doesn't work ...if I work with something basic.. like Blake give it to me... it works

Comment: It is something wrong with the code ? but I copied it from someone else

Comment: @Yang: when you say "I deleted the query-1.10.2.min.js" you mean that you fixed the typo and now you are pointing to the right jquery library? I suggest you again to look at the log of the web developer console (I don't know which browser you use, just search for it if you're still not using it :) ), so we can find out what's the exact error

Comment: I am using firefox.. and the log in web console is empty.

Comment: That's strange.
I've tried by myself and it works ([here's the code](http://dpaste.com/hold/1475447/) but it's exactly the same, i've just updated the references to some libraries, i've found new versions of them).

So what it's left now is:
 1) Put some `console.log` statements in the javascript code to understand if the flow is correct and eventually print variables to check if they're correct;
 2) Use a debugger (just to suggest something, the Firebug extension) to understand what happens.

Comment: I copied your code and paste it to my html. here is the error from webconsole log. I do not know how to fix it

Comment: [13:56:16.072] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @file:///User/renren/file/flot/lineFlot.html

Comment: [13:56:16.097] TypeError: $.formatNumber is not a function @ ile:///User/renren/file/flot/lineFlot.html:61:61

Comment: @Yang: glad you solved.
Just if someone else is coming to visit this question, the problem was that you didn't have the [Number Formatter JQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/) or it was not included properly (maybe another typo). Can you confirm that? Also maybe you can think to accept my answer.. ;)

Comment: yes, of course. yes, there is no formatNumber library. Can you help me to see temperature project by using flot? this is the project I am doing now. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20104567/revisions

Comment: how to contact you ? I am new to stackoverflow. And I do not how to send you email or send you my question..

Comment: No need to contact someone privately, when you have something to ask perform a research about your problem (probably there is an already existant question similar to what you want to ask). If your question is not already in stackoverflow, just ask as you did for this one. :)